# Issue with XML parsing and function in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to play in PHP with XML file.
It worked quite well up to moment I tried to introduce a function.

```
$mytournament = simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode(file_get_contents('tournament.xml')));


foreach($mytournament->CLUB as $CLUB){
    foreach ($CLUB->PERSON as $PERSON){
    echo $PERSON['FIRSTNAME'] . " " . $PERSON['LASTNAME'];
    }
}


function NOM($ARG1){
foreach($mytournament->CLUB as $CLUB){
    foreach ($CLUB->PERSON as $PERSON){
        if ($ARG1 == $PERSON['IDPERS']) {
            echo $PERSON['FIRSTNAME'] . " " . $PERSON['LASTNAME'];
        }
        else {
            echo "unknown name";
        }
    }
}
}
```

The first foreach is working well, while, the second into the function is making an error once the function is called.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I don't understand how to solve this issue which seems linked to function usage in php (??).

thanks for any hint

Comment: Can you also add the xml file you used?

Comment: Without seeing the source XML I cannot be sure, but that php error will usually mean that you aren't passing an array to foreach, check 
 $mytournament->CLUB|$club->person exists and isn't empty

Comment: yep but in that case, the 1st foreach would also fail which is not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$mytournament` is in global scope, and you try to access it within a function, and being in different scope, it becomes undefined therefore invalid argument error is shown. You have to either pass it as an argument to function or call it with global keyword.

```
$mytournament = simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode(file_get_contents('tournament.xml')));


foreach($mytournament->CLUB as $CLUB){
    foreach ($CLUB->PERSON as $PERSON){
    echo $PERSON['FIRSTNAME'] . " " . $PERSON['LASTNAME'];
    }
}
```

**Either Call it with `global`**

```
function NOM($ARG1){
    global $mytournament;
    foreach($mytournament->CLUB as $CLUB){
        foreach ($CLUB->PERSON as $PERSON){
            if ($ARG1 == $PERSON['IDPERS']) {
                echo $PERSON['FIRSTNAME'] . " " . $PERSON['LASTNAME'];
            }else {
                echo "unknown name";
             }
        }
    }
}
```

**Or pass it as an argument**

```
function NOM($ARG1, $mytournament){
    foreach($mytournament->CLUB as $CLUB){
        foreach ($CLUB->PERSON as $PERSON){
            if ($ARG1 == $PERSON['IDPERS']) {
                echo $PERSON['FIRSTNAME'] . " " . $PERSON['LASTNAME'];
            }else {
                echo "unknown name";
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a snippet of the actual code. It would also make no sense to do the same foreach in and out of the function.

Comment: removed my comment, op says first is working, although I don't see anything calling NOM at all

Comment: The usage of the `global` keyword is discouraged, and can provide multiple sources of problems.

Comment: indeed it may, but nevertheless a solution. :) thank you for the reminder, though

Comment: yep it is a snipped and having the same foreach twice is non sense except for debugging...

Comment: Missing `$` in the second argument of your function.